# Webservice - cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have the following method I am calling from a webservice - I keep getting an error message that "cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."

```
  [WebMethod]
    public ArrayList GetPayers()
    {
        string PROVIDER_JSON = "";

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            PROVIDER_JSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.eligibleapi.com/resources/information-sources.json");

            List<EligibleProviderType2> UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EligibleProviderType2>>(PROVIDER_JSON);

            for (int i = 0; i < UserList.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (string inventoryItem in UserList[i].PayerName)
                {
                    list.Add(new
                    {
                        PayerID = UserList[i].PayerID,
                        PayerName = inventoryItem
                    });
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
```

Which calls this class - which I thought has a parameterless constructor?

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class EligibleProviderType2
{
    EligibleProviderType2(){}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "payer_id")]
    public string PayerID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "names")]
    public IList<string> PayerName { get; set; }

} // EligibleProvider
```

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Make your constructor public.  The serialization code can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the constructor of your `EligibleProviderType2` is `private`. Private is the default for class fields and methods. Remove it (because the compiler will create one for you) or change as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class EligibleProviderType2
{
    public EligibleProviderType2(){}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "payer_id")]
    public string PayerID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "names")]
    public IList<string> PayerName { get; set; }
} // EligibleProvider
```

Comment: I copied the second block and pasted it and am still getting it - driving me crazy- so now I have: public EligibleProviderType2(){}

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: &lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.CreateUnknownTypeExcep

Comment: I see this line in the error: &lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]  - what is that?

Comment: I tried your example in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and it was able to deserialize correctly using JSON.NET. Make sure you have rebuilt and redeployed (if not testing locally from IIS Express). The JSON data I received contained 547 items.